# Independently control LEDs in series with intermediate point

Tags: led, impedance

I bought a bunch of LED bar arrays (DD-12 GWB KINGBRIGHT), with a relatively strange wiring diagram.

I would like to control each LED. It's easy for LED A, but B and C for example are wired together. How could I setup resistors and microcontroller pins?

I thought about setting pin 3 and 4 to GPIO, and 5 to resistor and GND, and use internal pull-up to block current in pin 4.

By the way, just being curious, does anyone understand why they design those bars like this?

[image: LED bar schematic]

Comment: Probably to special request from a very big customer. The rest of us get the wiring that customer wants.

Comment: How many microcontroller GPIOs have you got spare?

Comment: Or perhaps for reasons of PCB layout or the number of pins in the connector

Comment: @HandyHowie A whole arduino minus two pins :-)

Comment: The strange thing is that they could have put one common gnd and 12 pins, would have been so simpler for everyone :-)

Answer (score 2):

One half of this LED bar looks just right for [3-pin charlieplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlieplexing#Expanding:_tri-state_logic):

[image]

That will only work if the supply voltage is not enough to light two LEDs in series, though. For red LEDs on 3V3, it's alright.

To drive all the LEDs, 6 pins can be used, or 5:

[image]

Other multiplexing schemes could be devised, but if you want to be able to drive all the LEDs individually and have constant brightness no matter how many are lit, I don't think you can avoid multiplexing. If you use 3V3 you can't avoid it, because the two LEDs in series won't light.

So yeah, you'll need a timer interrupt with a bit of multiplexing code in it.

If both LEDs in series light (ie, two reds on 5V) you can try this one:

[image]

This lights at most 3 LEDs at a time, so it needs 4 multiplexing cycles since you have 12.

To have one IO per LED is a bit more complicated on the hardware side:

[image]

...because no matter what you do, when both LEDs are on, there will be 2 resistors in series, so there is much less current and they will be dimmer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply :-) I have a 5V output on a arduino, both LEDs light up in serie.

Comment: For me it's fine to use all my arduino GPIO :-)

Comment: I've updated the answer. But if you use one GPIO per LED, due to the resistors, current will be different if there's one or two in series, so the brightness will be uneven.

Comment: Thank you, i'm french and used to coma and long sentences :-) Will take care of it.

Comment: So i dont get it, how would you wire the Leds to control them one by one?

Comment: Is it about using persistence of vision and switch them fast?

Comment: Yes, fast switching and persistence of vision. That's how most displays with many LEDs operate, for example 7 segment clocks